# Need help on CSS to place these elements correctly

Tags: javascript, css

I have a css issue which I can't seem to figure out. I have a link to the application [here][1].

To use the app, just select a file (a small file for quick upload) and then click on the "Upload" button to upload the file. What you then see is the name of the file you have uploaded, the delete button and a horizontal line underneath.

But what I want is the name of the file to stay left like it is doing now, move the delete button to align right hand side inside the box and except using a horizontal line can that be replaced by using a dotted line?

Below is the  code where the filename, delete button and horizontal line is appended in:

```
<ul class='listImage' align='left'>
```

Below is the code which displays the filename, delete button and hozizontal line:

```
 $('.listImage').append(htmlEncode(imagefilename) + '<button align="right" type="button" class="deletefileimage">Delete</button><br/><hr/>');
```

Below is the current css for the listImage and delete button:

```
.deletefileimage{
    font-size:12px;
    font-weight:bold;   
}

.listImage{
    font-size:12px;
    text-align:left;
    margin:0;
    padding-left:0;

}
```

Comment: it doesnt look like you're adding `li` elements to the list.  Its invalid HTML otherwise.

Comment: @Kirean I will change it to a span tag later :) thanks for the notice

Comment: `<button type="button">`? I believe you want `<input type="button></input>` or `<button> </button>`.

Comment: @RASG `<button type="button">` is valid, and prevents the default behavior of buttons to be submit buttons.

Comment: @Kirean you're right. my mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace

```
<button align="right" type="button" class="deletefileimage">Delete</button>
```

with

```
<button style="float:right" type="button" class="deletefileimage">Delete</button>
```

Comment: please, don't promote inline-styling

Comment: Hey, thanks, I don't need a dotted line because the horizontal line does look good when delete button is moved to the right. Anyway I included this in the css. Thanks :)

Comment: @GNi33 inline styling is just fine.  Not everything *needs* to be in a CSS file.  While its good for using content over and over again (which is generally a use case), there are times when inline styling is needed or useful (in dynamic content, for example)

Answer (score 0):

`align='left'`  property is not good for browser capability , use `float:left; float:right;`